# Research database access friction

Tags: journals, databases, digital-libraries

Why is access to research databases (ebrary, EBSCO, JSTOR, LexisNexis, Project MUSE, Proquest, Sage, Science Direct, etc) – *even when you’re a student or faculty member at an institution with a subscription* - such a hassle, especially when off-campus or on a phone/tablet? Is there any way to solve this?

I’m also curious which database is least painful to deal with, and what a solution to this problem could be.  Who would be best positioned to fix this problem?  How should they fix it?

Comment: Generally institute subscription is based on IP address range of institute. You can not have that IP if you are not on institute network. However you can ask for VPN access, from that you can access institute network from outside. Now a days, many universities also offer special portal which you can use to browse various journals and databses.

Comment: I think this question needs to be thought through and made clearer, because it resembles a rant. If you are not aware that accessing these services requires a paid license, you should focus on that aspect. If you are asking about the technology of *verifying* that you are a student or faculty member at an institute with a paid subscription, then focus on that. The "hassle" usually comes from the library, not the database.

Comment: @user6726 as a librarian, I'd contest that. The hassle is *because* the database imposes access limits. No library is trying to make resources more complicated to access, and a lot of work goes into trying to reduce that friction...

Comment: I'm asking about the verification. In the question, I said "when you're a student or faculty member at an institution with a subscription", taking that as a given.

Comment: @jaith my experience is that the library's web interface is the problem. I don't think the hassle is intentional, it's just a consequence of not testing the interface adequately. My library still doesn't correctly detect that I am signed in so I have to sign in twice; the protocol for signing in (separate browser window popup) doesn't work in my tablet. Anyway, I urge you to edit the question and be more specific about the precise hassle.

Comment: @Andrew, as a librarian you approve the spending on the database therefore can get together with other librarian and tell the database provider that you will stop the spending if they don't make the access better.

Comment: @Ian If threats to drop our subscriptions unless they improve their service worked, we'd have done it for price rises :-). In all seriousness, most of the major providers do work to improve access, they're just *enormous* entities with a lot of legacy systems, and move glacially slowly.

Comment: Is your problem having to log in to each database? That problem can be solved easily on your end, using your browser's form autofill feature. You still have to click "login" but at least you won't have to type everything out. Also, see if the library can/would be willing to create a Webpage that lets you access the databases with a one-time login.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fundamental reason for friction is that these are commercially licensed resources, and so the licensors have a strong motive to ensure that only people who've paid for it in some way have access to them. Without that requirement, there'd be no reason to throw up the barriers.

The exact ways in which this friction manifests vary a lot - my understanding is that different access methods can be preferred in different places. I'll try and be general here, and explain what's currently used.

There are two basic methods for authorisation.

1. Site verification.
2. Individual verification.

The first of these involves identifying that you, the user, are coming from a site which has access. This is pretty trivial if you are on-campus and that campus has a defined IP range - "oh, they're coming from 1.2.3.4, they must be at Wherever University, let them in". In these cases, it can be completely seamless - in fact, so seamless that one real problem is that users can believe the resources are public, and get frustrated when they go home and they're not there! It also allows for 'walk-in' access - many licenses explicitly provide that if you're physically using the library, even as a visitor, you can access these databases. I am guessing from your post that you normally use this approach.

The second, individual verification, relies on each user having a signin to the database. This can be an enormous headache for both institutions and users, especially when you have *multiple* systems you need to sign in to. IP authentication is thus more popular.

However, IP verification breaks down if your institution shares its IP ranges with someone else (this is more common outside the West). If two institutions have a shared IP range, there's no practical way to provide access to users from one but block them from the other. If *most of a country* shares an IP range... you can see where this is going.

A similar problem arises if you are at an institution that uses IP authentication and you go somewhere else - perhaps you're at a conference, perhaps you're working from home, but either way you're not on the right network. One approach to get around this is to provide a VPN system, which drives all your traffic back through the "right" IPs. This is a hassle for users (and for the provider), and may not always be available. Another approach is to use a proxy server, but this is again something of a hassle for users. Both can lead to long network delays, and you have the associated problems of actually getting *into* the VPN/proxy server.

A common approach is to fall back on individual authentication. Most major databases offer optional individual logins, which let you save papers, set your viewing preferences, etc. These can be repurposed as logins which 'remember' that you have access rights, and let you use the service when away from your home network. They'll usually stop providing access after a while (a few weeks or months?) if you haven't signed in to it from your home network at some point, in order to prevent them remaining active forever. However, this still has the too-many-names problem of individual verification - no-one wants to juggle a ScienceDirect account *and* a JSTOR account *and* a Lexis account etc etc etc.

The best solution to this is to use an identity management/single sign-on system. The most common of these at the moment (less common in the US, I believe) is Shibboleth. Shibboleth provides a single login screen for all participating services. A user selects their home institution, is taken to a page there, signs in (or is automatically authenticated), and returns to the database service with authorised access. If done effectively, this can even completely replace IP authentication - you can do the necessary authentication for people on a local network automatically.

In theory, a system like Shibboleth should reduce friction **dramatically** - it can provide a standard sign-on system for all databases, and only require a single username/password which the user already knows (usually because it gets them into their email...). Compare to, eg, the ubiquitous "sign in with Facebook/Twitter/Google" buttons on web services. However, the problem is that each individual provider service has to set it up. The big databases like ScienceDirect or JSTOR are usually happy to do this, but small journals or databases - especially if the majority of their customers are happy with IP authentication - may not be willing to go to the effort of setting it up.

In an ideal world, we'd all be standardising on something like this. Unfortunately, there's a lot of people who all have to pull in the same direction for it to happen, and what is most convenient for publishers is not always what's most convenient for libraries or for users.

Comment: * 0
down vote
 

*The fundamental reason for friction is that these are commercially licensed resources, and so the licensors have a strong motive to ensure that only people who've paid for it in some way have access to them* OP is asking about people who have access via their institution.

Comment: @CapeCode That's addressed by the next sentence - *Without that requirement, there'd be no reason to throw up the barriers.* The barriers that are "friction" to people who have access via their institution are only there at all to restrict access to authorized users.

Comment: _If most of a country shares an IP range... you can see where this is going_ Never mind that: There actually exists a _whole country using a single IP address:_ [Qatar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_talk:82.148.97.69).

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist Indeed - I think Thailand had the same situation (for a while, at least). I believe that in some cases, universities end up buying a proxy server elsewhere (eg in the US) and routing all their traffic to external databases through that in order to make sure IP-based authentication works welll

Comment: @CapeCode As ff524 says, it's not that there's friction because you don't have access, it's that there's friction involved in *showing* that you have access and aren't one of the many people who don't...

Comment: @ff524 I don't understand. If the barriers are to prevent access to non-subscribers, then they should not be present for subscribers. Unless you consider logging in to your library account "friction".

Answer (score 2):

Why is this a hassle? One of the motivations, and in many cases the primary motivation, of those hosting the databases is to make money via subscription fees. For example LexisNexis is a subdivision of Elsevier, a company which made over US$1,000,000,000 in profits last year and which is the subject of an ongoing [boycott](http://thecostofknowledge.com). The financial interests of companies like Elsevier dictate that their first priority is to make research inaccessible to those who have not paid.

In the short term, your university library might be able to make this easier by means of a VPN or something similar. You might contact your librarian and ask for instructions (which will be specific to your institution).

In the long term, you can help this problem by publishing your research in open-access, freely available venues. For example in mathematics it is common to publish papers in journals and also (in preprint form) to the free, open-access [arXiv](http://arxiv.org). Doing so helps to reduce our dependence on closed-access venues such as the ones you described.

Answer (score 1):

**Low demand.**

The vast majority of researchers have little knowledge about these and to what purpose they can be used. An increasing number of scholars have a hard time locating the library on campus or mentioning an online service from their library or one to which it subscribed.

Also, these are relatively modest commercial operations, and we are increasingly used to highly efficient data queries and search engines. There is no way they can compete e.g. with a Google service in terms of absence of "friction".